# calculate ellipse tangential to 2 other ellipses sharing 1 focus

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

## Problem

As illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQZjy.png), i have two ellipses ($E_0$ aand $E_1$) both with $(0,0)$ as their one focus point.
The other focuspoint ($f_0$) of $E_0$ lies on the negative side of the x axis per definition, but the other focuspoint ($f_1$) of $E_1$ can lie anywhere.
I do also know the major and minor axie of both ellipses, in this particular illustration $E_0$ lies inside $E_1$ but this is not necesarrily always the case.
**However** it is per definition always true that $E_0$ and $E_1$ never intersect oneanother.

Given a specific point $A$ on $E_0$ i want to draw a third ellipse $E_2$, whose one focus also must be at $(0,0)$ and which is tangential to $E_0$ exactly at $A$ and tangential to $E_1$ at any point.

## My solution this far

This problem really comes down to finding the other focus ($f_2$) of $E_2$.

By doing some experiments i have found that in order to be tangential to $E_0$, $f_2$ must lie on a ray from $A$ through $f_0$, (which also implies that $B$ must lie on the intersection between $E_1$ and a ray from $f_1$ through $f_0$) – this can also be seen in the [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQZjy.png).
I have not been able to come up with a proof for this, but since it seems to be the case in all the experiments i have made, i assume it to always be true.
Therefor the problem simplifies to finding the correct distance $l$ between $A$ and $f_2$.

I have been able to find a way of calculating the $B$ (as the intersection between $E_1$ and the ray from $f_1$ through $f_2$) from a known $l$ (which is descriped later).
When i do have $B$ i can calculate the distances from $B$ to $(0,0)$ and from $B$ to $f_2$ (which easilly can be calculated from l), only if the sum of these to distances is equal to the sum of the distances from $A$ to $(0,0)$ and from $A$ to $f_2$ does $B$ lie on $E_2$, which (if my previous assumption is true) implies that the $E_2$ is tangential to both $E_0$ and $E_1$.

It also appears that as $l$ aproached the correct value, the difference between the previously mentioned sums aproach $0$ (no matter if $l$ aproaches the correct value from a greater or smaller value; therefor i have this far been able to recursively (since this is all a part of a simulation which i am programming) find an almost acceptable aproximation for $l$.

There are two problems with this: firstly it is only an aproximation, and secondly it is recursive, and even though it is acceptably accurate, and acceptably fast, i do still not like the idea of using a recursive aproximation if a way of calculating $E_2$ correctly exist.

### Calculating $B$

This is way i have been able to calculate the point $B$, though i can not say for sure that a more logical and simple aproach to this could exist.

Firstly, to easilly find the intersection between $E_1$ the ray from $f_1$ through $f_2$, i transform $E_1$, $A$, $f_0$ and $f_1$ so that $E_1$ can be defined as $1=\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{x^2}{a^2}$, this is done by multiplying all points and direction with a four dimensional matrix which i have in my simulation, and which beyond all reasonable doubt transforms correctly (my specific matrix always transforms $f_1$ to the negative side of the x axis and the focus which before was at (0,0) to the positive side of the x axis).

The point $f_2$ then becomes $\vec{f_2}=|\vec{a}-\vec{f_0}|l$ (In my simulation the points are saved as vectors, therefor this is valid) the direction of the ray from $f_1$ through $f_2$ is then $\vec{ray}=\vec{f_1}-\vec{f_2}$.
Then the $y=s\cdot x+m$ eqaution for this ray can be found, since $s=\frac{\vec{r}_y}{\vec{r}_x}$ and $m=\vec{f_1}_y-s\cdot\vec{f_1}_x$.

Then finding the x coordinate of $B$ is simply a matter of finding the intersection between an ellipse defined by $1=\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{x^2}{a^2}$ and a ray with a known equation, which comes down to solving this equation of the second degree: $0=x^2\cdot (\frac{s^2}{b^2}+\frac{1}{a^2})+x\cdot( \frac{2\cdot s\cdot m}{b^2})+\frac{m^2}{b^2}-1$.
This does yield two solutions, but if $s$ is positive, then the smallest sollution is true, otherwise it is the greatest which is true (in my case, where the transformation matrix transforms $f_1$ to a negative x value on the x axis).
The y coordinate can then be found by inserting the found x coordinate into the eqaution of the ray $y=s\cdot x+m$.

Finally the coordinates of $B$ can be transformed back to the original space, by using the inverse transformation matrix.

## question specification

My question is if there is a way of calculating the correct position of $f_2$ (without recursively aproximating it as i do) so that $E_2$ can become tangential, under the conditions outlined in the »problem« section. If this is possiple i would like to know how.

No matter if it is possiple or not, i would – if possible – like to see a proof of why it is so.

Comment: This problem is solved through old-school Euclidean geometry in this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168522/ellipse-tangential-to-two-arbitrary-ellipses-sharing-a-focus/2168625?noredirect=1#comment4460096_2168625

Comment: The answer to that question is correct, with the slight modification that instead of a hyperbola as in that question, in which the ellipses may intersect onanother, the correct locations lie on an ellipse with focuspoints $f_0$ and $f_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after my own question, someone else posted a similar problem, but where the first two ellipses do intersect oneanother, in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168522/ellipse-tangential-to-two-arbitrary-ellipses-sharing-a-focus/2168625?noredirect=1#comment4460096_2168625) the answer posted by Jack D'Aurizio was that the correct other focuspoint of the transfer ellipse, always lie on a hyperbola through a point I on the line between $f_1$ and $f_0$, where it is true that $|f_1I|+|f_0I|=a_{E_1}-a_{E_0}$ (where $a$ is the major axis of the ellipses, and $|f_1I|$ and $|f_0I|$ is the distances between I and $f_1$ and $f_0$)

This is however only true when the ellipses intersect oneanother, as ccorn correctly pointed pointed out in a comment, in my case where the ellipses don't intersect (or as he said $|a_{E_1}-a_{E_0}|>|f_0f_1|$ then the correct $f_2$ lies on an ellipse, with focuspoints $f_0$ and $f_1$ and through $I$

The specific point $f_2$ is furthermore exactly the one of the intersections between the ray from $A$ through $f_0$ and the previously mentioned ellipse, which lies furtherst from $A$.